# Magento 2 Form Admin Email address issue

Tags: magento, magento2

I have a problem. In Magento 2.4 I have two stores, store A and store B. Both use the same form. I created separate but identical forms for each store. In the form options I have an Admin Email address that is displayed next to the incoming email. Unfortunately, regardless of the store, it still comes with the same Admin Email address. Each form has a different email address. Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

What did you have in your magento configuration on "General/Contacts" tab and "Email options" section? I'm not sure what forms do you use, but maybe try change scope from default to B store and modify "Send Emails To" config?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't think it has anything to do with it. I use Mage Arrey extension and there are forms. Also in these options I can specify the Mail from which the messages come.